# C++: a list with "const pointer" as members VS a list with "pointer to const" as members

Tags: c++, list, pointers, mfc, constants

My apologies if this question has been asked.

I'm aware the meaning and syntax difference between "const pointer" vs "pointer to const".

char * const myPtr; is a "const pointer" and can not be used as "myPtr = &char_B;"

const char * myPtr; is a "pointer to const" and can not be used as "*myPtr = 'J';"

If I'm using MFC's container, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw2702d6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I want to listen to your comments about my statement:

1. CObList or CPtrList can not fulfill my requirement, correct?
2. My first thinking is to use CTypedPtrList, for example:

   CTypedPtrList means a list with members that are "const pointers".

This actually works but "useless":

```
class CAge
{
public:
    int   m_years;
    CAge( int age ) { m_years = age; }
};

CTypedPtrList<CPtrList, CAge* const> list;
list.AddTail(new CAge(10));
list.AddTail(new CAge(5));

POSITION pos = list.GetHeadPosition();
while(pos)
{
    CAge* a = (CAge*)list.GetNext(pos);
    a = new CAge(11);  //That's why I say it is "useless", because the returned value can be assigned

    list.GetNext(pos) = new CAge(11);   //Expected, can not pass compile
}
```

1. However, CTypedPtrList is not working. I want a list with "pointer to const" members and MORE.

   ```
   CTypedPtrList<CPtrList, const CAge*> list2;
   //list2.AddTail(new CAge(10));          //Help! This does not pass compile, then how to initialize list2???
   //list2.AddTail(new CAge(5));

   POSITION pos2 = list2.GetHeadPosition();
   while(pos2)
   {
       CAge* a = (CAge*)list2.GetNext(pos2);
       a->m_years = 50;    //This passed compile. That's why I say "MORE".

       //((CAge*)list2.GetNext(pos2))->m_years = 50;       //This passed compile (because of type cast)
       //((const CAge*)list2.GetNext(pos2))->m_years = 50; //this does not pass compile (because of type cast as well)
   }
   ```
2. Actually, for the above scenario, I actually want a "magic" list. if a pointer (non constant pointer) was added to this "magic" list, then later the retrieval of the pointer **from the list** will be a "constant pointer", can not use the pointer to change the content of the pointed object.

**The question:** How to define the "magic" list?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to force new objects to be `const`. The type system only ensures that references/pointers to old objects remain `const`.

As for `CAge* a = (CAge*)list2.GetNext(pos2);`, just remove the cast. Casts break the type system (in fact this is the point of casts), so you should not be surprised that they allow you to modify objects through `const` reference paths.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, as you said, if I use "CAge* a = list2.GetNext(pos2);" then the compiler can catch the error "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const CAge *' to 'CAge *'"; However, if I use "CAge* a = list.GetNext(pos);", I can still call "a = new CAge(11);" afterwards. Does it mean my comment on const pointer in the container as "useless" still stand?

Comment: Another question, what is the possible way to initialize a list that contains "pointer to const" members? Do you know if there is a way to define such "magic" list as described in the last section?